# How to properly escape %s in sql query

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have the following sql:

```
sql = '''SELECT DISTINCT artwork_apple_url FROM main_catalog 
         WHERE (artwork_url IS NULL OR artwork_url NOT LIKE '%s3-%')
           UNION ALL
         SELECT DISTINCT artwork_apple_url FROM main_collectioninstance 
         WHERE (artwork_url IS NULL OR artwork_url NOT LIKE '%s3-%')
      '''
cursor.execute(sql)
```

This gives me a formatting error -- How would I get the `LIKE %s3-%'` in my sql (`s3` is part of an Amazon url).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use [parametrized SQL](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/), the quoting of the arguments will be done by the DB adapter for you. It's easier and helps prevent SQL injection. Note that the appropriate placemarker (e.g. the `%s`) depends on the DB adapter you are using. `%s` is appropriate for MySQLdb, but `?` is the placemarker symbol used by oursql, for example.

```
sql = '''SELECT DISTINCT artwork_apple_url FROM main_catalog 
         WHERE (artwork_url IS NULL OR artwork_url NOT LIKE %s)
           UNION ALL
         SELECT DISTINCT artwork_apple_url FROM main_collectioninstance 
         WHERE (artwork_url IS NULL OR artwork_url NOT LIKE %s)
      '''
cursor.execute(sql, ['%s3-%']*2)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this is the correct answer, and works with MySQLdb as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
Place a backward slash before each percentage symbol you wish to escape and insert this function on the same line: ESCAPE '\'
```

From here: http://www.ehow.com/how_8601061_escape-special-character-sql.html?dmsp=manual